# How to resolve contradictory thoughts on finding preimages of the logistic map.

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

Take the logistic map with parameter 4, so $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$.  Moreover, suppose we are iterating the logistic map using finite precision, and hence rounding off to the last decimal place after every iteration.  Say, for the sake of argument, that these points have 20 digits in the decimal expansion, and call the set of all such points between 0 and 1 with 20 digit decimal representations $E$.

Then if I take any point $E$ and iterate it under the logistic map, I will get some string of iterates also in $E$, where the sequence of iterates must repeat (is periodic) after no more than $10^{20}$ iterations (because we are staying in $E$ for every iteration).

But suppose I wanted to find the set of preimages of $f$ over a point.  Then for each point in $x_0 \in E$, the fiber of $x$ under $f$, that is $f^{-1}(\{x_0\})$ is a set of two points also in $E$, where I can compute $f^{-1}(x_0)$ using the quadratic formula for the polynomial $-4x^2+4x-x_0$ (and similarly rounding off the result so that I get two points $a, b$ in $E$, so that $f(a)=f(b) = x_0$).

As such, every time I compute $f^{-1}(x_0) = \{a, b\}$, I get two points in $E$, and so if I compute $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ the same thing happens.  So I have a "binary tree" that I can build up from some "root point" $x_0$. But if I recurse back and built up this binary tree, after very few iterations I will have "covered" the entire set of points $E$.  In fact the number of levels in this binary tree will be far fewer than say $10^{20}$, the maximum period of some orbit.  For example, after 100 recursive iterations back up this tree, we get $2^{100}$ leaves at the top, and $2^{100} > 10^{20}$, so after just 100 of these rounds we have already gone far beyond the number of points in $E$.

The contradiction is, then, that if after building up say $100$ levels of the binary tree, I have covered all points, then if I follow each point back down the tree in the opposite direction, I hit $x_0$ after at most $100$ iterations, implying every point in $E$ "converges onto the same orbit", which is clearly not what is going on.

Can anyone explain where my logic is flawed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things could be wrong here.

First, you don't know that you will cover the entire set of points of $E$. The only thing you know is that, as soon as $2^n > 10^{20}$, some values have to be repeated at the $n$-th level. You don't know they will cover all of $E$.

Second, because you are rounding at each step, you don't know that if you start with a number $x \in E$, then compute the *rounded* version $y \in E$ of a preimage $f^{-1}(x)$, and then compute the *rounded* version of $f(y) \in E$, you would necessarily end up back at $x$. So the naive relationship $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ might not hold due to the rounding. Walking down and then back up the tree might not take you back where you started.

It shouldn't be difficult to implement this at a smaller scale (e.g. use $10^5$ instead of $10^{20}$) which lets you see these issues.